# Bullets in list don't allow white space or border

Tags: css, list

How can I create a white space border between items in a list?
I tried to to this, but then there's no white space between the bullets:
Also, I write css inline, because it is for newsletters.

```
<ul style="color: white;background:#e2000b;">
    <li><b>38%</b></li>
    <li style="border-top:5px white solid;"><b>Free</b></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/4EAq3/

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ showing the issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4EAq3/

Comment: @Tanner Theres a background colour set on the `ul`, so white will be visible.

Comment: How can I create white space between the two items, and still give the bullet and the item a red bgcolor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:
http://jsfiddle.net/4EAq3/8/

I used `list-style-position:inside` on the list.

Comment: Nice one. Never knew about this.

Comment: This was going to be my solution too, position inside with zero margin and padding. However instead of a background on the whole list I did it with margin bottom and bg colour on the list items themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo element to show white-space between list elements. Don't use inline styles.

```
<ul style="color: white;background:#e2000b;">
    <li><b>38%</b></li>
    <li style="border-top:5px white solid;position:relative;"><b>Free</b><div style="position:absolute;top:-5px;left:-40px;width:40px;height:5px;background:#fff;"></div></li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4EAq3/5/)

Comment: I have to use inline styles, it's for newsletters

Comment: Sorry, it can't be done in inline styles but you can create a child like div and apply the properties of pseudo element to it.